# is 'dyld library not loaded- image not found' an error in the simulator or an error in the app extension?

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode8, apple-watch

When I run a build with the simulator it crashes with this error, saying 'dyld: Library not loaded' and also 'image not found';

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
   Referenced from:      /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/105F223C-3558-46E2-B3C0-CEF7E29B6B3D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D0F33E52-59FC-46EA-B1FF-DBE191CA4DD2/Watch.app/PlugIns/Watch Extension.appex/Watch Extension
```

Is this a simulator error, or an app code error?  I would like to know if I can upload the app to the App store, or would it be an invalid build because of this error?

Also, any ideas on how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot upload to the App Store this way, though I don't know why you would want to since you can't test your app.

Go to your main application and try turning on `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` (this was called `Embedded Content Contains Swift` in earlier releases).

Sometimes if the main app target doesn't have any Swift code or you have a plugin situation Xcode doesn't realize it should be including the Swift standard library in your bundle. In this case, for whatever reason, Xcode doesn't think `Watch.app` needs Swift so it doesn't include it even though your extension does use Swift.